# search plugin for marlin,nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, marlin

I installed marlin file browser in ubuntu 11.10 but it have no search box is there any plugin to do it ?
Is there any alternate search box for nautilus?

Comment: You may not know this but, Marlin is not part of Ubuntu, it is part of elementary and they have a Launchpad page where you can ask *them* for this they also have a Q6A site and a FB page. AS for the Nautilus searchbox, if you mean the one that appears when you input text and locates a file based on the letter you typed , No that's hardcoded into Nautilus.

Comment: I mean default search box in nautilus  it does not display full results
it start to display results after entire search is completed

file extension type search is not possible (wrong?)
eg: *.jpg


but in marlin nothing is there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marlin file browser is still in development and it means that you can miss some features.

Marlin can search files. but only on the folder that you are viewing, to do that you only need to type the name and then a textbox appear in the right botton edge of the program.

Do not forget to report bugs and ask for features in the marlin lauchpad to help the project.

Other option is to write a plugin but i don't know if there are an api or something to do that.

https://launchpad.net/marlin